# LocalDB build and Memory Optimized table types

Tags: sql-server, azure-sql-database, memory-optimized-tables, sql-server-localdb

We have a DevOps pipeline for our DB Build/Release process and we're using VS SQL Database projects. We have one DB which makes extensive use of memory optimized table variables.  Used for transfering data to/from a Calc Engine & DB.  I know that LocalDB doesn't support FILESTREAM (needed for MO tables), but I'm not looking to nail up a LocalDB.

QUESTION: can LocalDB handle DB build/release process for validation purposes?  If no, will I need a permanent Azure SQL DB for this purpose?

Comment: LocalDB is a non-starter for MO objects for the reason you mentioned. Have you considered a [database container](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63538477/how-do-i-get-mssql-service-container-working-in-azure-devops-pipeline)?

Comment: Thanks @DanGuzman!  It was an answer I didn't want - but I think you're right.  Thanks for the tip.  I'll look into the database container idea.  Have a great Thanksgiving!